# Help me Verifying that the equation is integrable and finding its solution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential-geometry, curves

How can I verify that the equation is integrable and that find its solution;

$$2y(a-x)dx+[z-y^2+(a-x)^2]dy-ydz=0$$

Honestly, I tried too much, but I got too strange results,thus I couldnt show my efforts here so sorry. Thank you for helping.

Comment: you could add tags (differential)geometry or curves

Comment: Okay tagged @DylanZhu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

1-Verify that
$$
curl \left(2y(a-x),\,z-y^2+(a-x)^2,\,-y\right)=(0,0,0)
$$
Actually, it is not true. May be there is a typo. I believe the second component of the vector field is $-[z-y^2+(a-x)^2]$.

2- Find the potential of the vector field $\left(2y(a-x),\,-[z-y^2+(a-x)^2],\,-y\right)$.

edit:

You need a function $f$ such that $\nabla f(x,y,z)=\left(2y(a-x),\,-[z-y^2+(a-x)^2],\,-y\right)$. Then
$$
f(x,y,z)=\int 2y(a-x)\,dx+C(y,z)=-y(a-x)^2+C(y,z)
$$
If we derive in $y$
$$
-[z-y^2+(a-x)^2]= f_y(x,y,z)=-(a-x)^2+C_y(y,z)
$$
then
$$
C(y,z)=-zy+\frac{y^3}{3}+B(z)
$$
and
$$
f(x,y,z)=-y(a-x)^2-zy+\frac{y^3}{3}+B(z)
$$
Now, if we derive in $z$:
$$
-y=f_z(x,y,z)=-y+B'(z)
$$
Then...

Comment: Okay, I showed this is integrable. Now I'm trying to find its solution. For this, firstly, keep $z$ constant. And I need to find $$2y(a-x)dx+[z-y^2+(a-x)^2]dy=0$$ I tried too many times. But I cannot. Can you show me please? Thankslot for helping :)

Comment: I used the website wolframalpha but its solution is too strange.

Comment: I wrote some details. You are looking for a surface $f(x,y,z)=cte$.

Comment: Okay thank you very much